# How to redirect to another link stored in the database using php?

Tags: php, redirect

I am currently working with a database named "DBO" and a table named "Register". There is a column named "personal_website_link" which stores personal webpage links given by users. I want to redirect to that particular website link after a user clicked a button.

i have used following HTML code to the button:

```
**<a href="link.php" type="url" class="link" target="_blank"> </a>**
```

The PHP file code is as follows,

```
**<?php 
include_once('config.php');
$personal_website_link= 'SELECT* FROM* register';
$column['personal_website_link'];
 

    Header("Location: $personal_website_link");
    exit();
?>**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   include_once('config.php');
   $personal_website_link= 'SELECT * FROM * register';
   $column['personal_website_link'];
   header('Location: ' . $personal_website_link);
   exit();
?>
```